# ¿puedo ocultar widgets con tkinter en pyhton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo una duda con respecto a usar las widgets que se crean con Tkinter en python, cunado creo uno por ejemplo:

```
mensaje = tkinter.Label(window, text="Example")
boton = tkinter.Button(window, text="Mostrar", command=mostrarMensaje)
mensaje.pack()
boton.pack()
```

en donde o en que puedo definir que se pueda ocultar o no visualizar el **Label** hasta realizar un metodo o una tarea con un boton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ocultar con `pack()` utiliza `pack_forget()`, con `grid()` utiliza `grid_remove()`. Para volver a mostrar solo colócalo otra vez (ya sea con pack o grid)

Te recomiendo usar `grid` en vez de `pack`, esto ya que grid tiene un método llamado `grid_remove()` que oculta el widget pero guarda la información que este tiene, así que cuando lo vuelvas a mostrar quedara exactamente igual a como estaba antes.

Con `pack()`

```
def mostrarMensaje():
    mensaje.pack() #Muestro

window = Tk()
mensaje = Label(window, text="Example")
mensaje.pack() #Muestro
mensaje.pack_forget() #Oculto
boton = Button(window, text="Mostrar", command=mostrarMensaje)
boton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Con `grid()`

```
from tkinter import * 


def mostrarMensaje():
    mensaje.grid() #Muestro

window = Tk()
mensaje = Label(window, text="Example")
mensaje.grid(row=1, column=0) #Muestro
mensaje.grid_remove()  #Oculto
boton = Button(window, text="Mostrar", command=mostrarMensaje)
boton.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mucha gracias, me funciono en ambos casos.

Pero tengo una duda, con `grid()` tambien tengo funciones de estilo como con `pack()` ya sea como **side, fill, expand** entre otros?